# Iterative and conditional deleting of lines in a file

Tags: macos, bash, random, awk, sed

## Intro

I have a file named `data.dat` with the following structure:

```
    1:    67:     1 :s
    1:   315:     1 :s
    1:   648:     1 :ns
    1:   799:     1 :s
    1:   809:     1 :s
    1:   997:     1 :ns
    2:    32:     1 :s
```

## Algorithm

The algorithm that I'm looking for is:

1. Generate a random number between 1 and number of lines in this file.
2. Delete that line if the fourth column is "s".
3. Otherwise generate another random number and repeat this until the number of lines reaches to a certain value.

## Technical Concepts

Though technical concepts are irrelevant to this algorithm, but I try to explain the problem. The data shows connectivity table of a network. This algorithm allows us to run it over different initial conditions and study general properties of these networks. Especially, because of randomness property of deleting bonds, any common behavior among these networks can be interpreted as a fundamental law.

**Update**: Another good reason to produce a random number in each step is that after removing each line, it's possible that property of being `s`/`ns` of remaining lines can be changed.

## Code

Here is the code I have until now:

```
#!/bin/bash
# bash in OSX

While ((#there is at least 1 s in the fourth column)); do

   LEN=$(grep -c "." data.dat)  # number of lines
   RAND=$((RANDOM%${LEN}+1))    # generating random number

   if [[awk -F, "NR==$RAND" 'data.dat' |  cut -d ':' -f 4- == "s"]]; then
         sed '$RANDd' data.txt
   else
         #go back and produce another random
done
exit
```

I try to find the fourth column with `awk -F, "NR==$RAND" 'data.dat' |  cut -d ':' -f 4-` and deleting the line by `sed '$RANDd' data.txt`.

## Questions

1. How should I check that there is `s` pairs in my file?
2. I am not sure if the condition in `if` is correct.
3. Also, I don't know how to force loop after `else` to go back to generate another random number.

Thank you,

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You're deleting every line that ends with ":s". Why bother with random numbers and iteration?

Comment: It might sound technical but this is a network that I am interested in percolation and its flexibility under random removing of bonds.

Comment: @JohnB: I know that the fastest way is to remove all lined with `s` but this is only one part of the study. As in future, I am intended to study these networks before reaching to the specific threshold (with no s). Basically, if I can run this, I have a program to run for any final number of `s` rows. Also it's important to remove the lines randomly to avoid any biased result.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to update your question with details to justify exactly how `RANDOM` is needed for a network study.  Also, there are numerous syntax errors in your code.  [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) might help.

Comment: I was wondering, have you tried any of the answers?

Comment: @TomFenech: Yes I was trying all three and I just accepted your answer as the answer. Thank you for this nice answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would recommend against doing this in bash unless you have absolutely no choice.

Here's another way you could do it in Perl (quite similar in functionality to [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26082247/2088135) but a bit simpler):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = shift;
open my $fh, "<", $filename or die "could not open $filename: $!";
chomp (my @lines = <$fh>);

my $sample = 0;
my $max_samples = 10;
while ($sample++ < $max_samples) {
    my $line_no = int rand @lines;
    my $line = $lines[$line_no];
    if ($line =~ /:s\s*$/) {
        splice @lines, $line_no, 1;
    }
}

print "$_\n" for @lines;
```

Usage: `perl script.pl data.dat`

Read the file into the array `@lines`. Pick a random line from the array and if it ends with :s (followed by any number of spaces), remove it. Print the remaining lines at the end.

This does what you want but I should warn you that relying on built-in random number generators in any language is not a good way to arrive at statistically significant conclusions. If you need high-quality random numbers, you should consider using a module such as [Math::Random::MT::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~jfreeman/Math-Random-MT-Perl-1.05/lib/Math/Random/MT/Perl.pm) to generate them, rather than the built-in `rand`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# usage: $ excise.pl < data.dat > smaller_data.dat

my $sampleLimit = 10; # sample up to ten lines before printing output

my $dataRef;
my $flagRef;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    push (@{$dataRef}, $_);
    push (@{$flagRef}, 1);
}
my $lineCount = scalar @elems;
my $sampleIndex = 0;
while ($sampleIndex < $sampleLimit) {
    my $sampleLineIndex = int(rand($lineCount));
    my @sampleElems = split("\t", $dataRef->[$sampleLineIndex];
    if ($sampleElems[3] == "s") {
        $flagRef->[$sampleLineIndex] = 0;
    }
    $sampleIndex++;
}
# print data.dat to standard output, minus any sampled lines that had an 's' in them
foreach my $lineIndex (0..(scalar @{$dataRef} - 1)) {
    if ($flagRef->[$lineIndex] == 1) {
        print STDOUT $dataRef->[$lineIndex]."\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NumLine=$( grep -c "" data.dat )
while [ ${NumLine} -gt ${TargetLine} ]
 do
   # echo "Line at start: ${NumLine}"

   RndLine=$(( ( ${RANDOM} % ${NumLine} ) + 1 ))
   RndValue="$( echo "      ${RANDOM}" | sed 's/.*\(.\{6\}\)$/\1/' )"

   sed "${RndLine} {
          s/^\([^:]*:\)[^:]*\(:.*:ns$\)/\1${RndValue}\2/
          t
          d
          }" data.dat > /tmp/data.dat
   mv /tmp/data.dat data.dat
   NumLine=$( grep -c "" data.dat )

   #cat data.dat
   #echo "- Next Iteration -------"
 done
```

tested on AIX (so not a GNU sed). Under Linux, use `--posix` for sed option and you can use a `-i` in place of temporary file + redirection + move in this case

Dont't forget that `RANDOM` is NOT a real RANDOM so study on network behavior based on not random value could not reflect a reality bu a specific case